# Add/remove EnumProperty items?

Tags: python

So I want to use in my addon enum for dropdown menu and two buttons to add/remove items from it.

[image]

Now hard (foe me) part. How the hell add or remove anything to those "items" inside EnumProperty?????

Yes I already saw [this API page](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.83/bpy.props.html). Yes I already watch N videos about getter/setter and I even think I understand now what it is.

But those videos about pure python, not something "items" inside something other "EnumProperty" inside some Blender API.

Example on API page looks like some bullshit joke and give "0" clues what to do to access this items somehow....

[image]

Like get_enum and then import random and then return random WHAT??? ?
set_enum and then print some value WHAAAATTTT??? ?
Why not just show how the hell call to not just read but edit those damn "items" from some operator?

I tried to google almost everything can come in to mind, none of google search give any clues how to work with this thing. My last hope - someone here just show some example of how it work/look.

Comment: I'd advise you to look into [CollectionProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.83/bpy.props.html?highlight=collectionproperty#bpy.props.CollectionProperty) but you may benefit from following a crash course in python before diving further into the API

Comment: Nice advice, I will go and read this documentation... aha, again... Good job...